# Google Sheet see two different value as same value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As i tried to combine value between two table into one, I got 2 string values that Google Sheet somehow treated it as same value. When in fact, They are different value and they should return a different value as well.

[Made-up sheet. And yes, I tried $A:$A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG8LB.png)

This does look like nothing happen. Each value return different result as expected.
However, When i tried this in my real worksheet which contain about thousands of row. This happened.

[Real sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SNq8.png)

I set custom conditional formatting so whenever there are duplicates, The cell will highlight rightaway. Which is how i found out about this.

It's as if Google Sheet saw '114-53' and '1-1453' and treated as '11453' instead of two separated values. The weird things is it doesn't happened in my dummy sheet. And for some reason i simply just can't replicated it.

I tried nested UNIQUE inside INDEX/MATCH = doesn't work

i tried VLOOKUP instead = doesn't work either.

QUERY each row slow everything down to a crawl. And query /w textjoin return in result that doesn't match with another dataset i need to compare. So now i have no idea how to fix this. Anyone know what caused this and recommended some kind of workaround? I looked for answer everywhere and found nothing. Thank you for your assistance in advance.

[EDIT] I manage to replicated the issue in dummy file. Here's sheet link.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gy4WlQcH4L3MXlbvF-dWPQ_o8FjwvyR5m8rDxEf0tQQ/edit#gid=585292121

Comment: You are showing us tiny glimpses of isolated cells of spreadsheets, which means we can't test anything: data types, formatting, etc. It's the equivalent of showing us a centimeter of a painting and asking us to guess the artist. My only *guess* would be that values in your real sheet really *are* `11453` and are merely being formatted in places to *look like* `114-53` or `1-1453`. Beyond that guess, I can only invite you share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), so that we can see "the whole painting."

Comment: @Erik Tyler That's the problem. I simply can't replicated the problem in a new sheet. It worked fine if you have only two rows. Thus unable to share you anything without actually copy thousands of internal sensitive company data. I'll try using importrange and see if I can make a new sheet without actually have to share the whole thing.

Comment: It should be possible to make a copy of the full sheet and just delete data from any columns that contain real names or email addresses, since those aren't involved directly in the issue. Or even make a full copy, then delete everything except for the example shown in your images and let us know where to find that one example. If your real spreadsheet has multiple sheets to it, you can copy just the sheet that contains the issue off to a new spreadsheet and sanitize it as I've explained here.

Comment: @Erik Tyler Okay i manage to replicated the result. Here's the link to my dummy file.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gy4WlQcH4L3MXlbvF-dWPQ_o8FjwvyR5m8rDxEf0tQQ/edit#gid=585292121

I'll edit and add it in my question.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A, "-", "♦"), 
 {SUBSTITUTE(sheet1!A:E, "-", "♦"), ROW(sheet1!A:A)} , {3, 6}, 0), "N/A")))
```

[image]